# warning with const operator (in struct)

Tags: c, struct, constants

it may be a nooby question but i cant figure out why i get a warning

struct4.c:32:15: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default] crea[i].size = wsize[i%5];

compiling this:

```
struct shirt {
     char *size;
    char *colour;
} ;
    typedef struct shirt Camicia;

void loadshirt (Camicia * const crea, const char *wsize[] , const char *wcolour[]);


int main (void) {

    Camicia collezione[50];

    const char *sizearray[] = {"xs","s","m","l","xl"};
    const char *colourarray[] = {"black","blue","yellow","orange"};

    loadshirt(collezione,sizearray,colourarray);

    printf("%s\n",collezione[4].size);
    printf("%s\n",collezione[4].colour);

    return 0;
}

void loadshirt (Camicia * const crea, const char *wsize[] , const char *wcolour[]) {

    int i=0;

    while (i<50) {
    crea[i].size = wsize[i%5];
    crea[i].colour = wcolour[i%4];
    i++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Indent your code, please. It's hard to read it now.

Comment: You edited your question to change `Camicia const * crea` to `Camicia * const crea`.  The answers you've gotten are pointing to this as the problem.  Which is it?

Comment: BTW, your code will SEGFAULT when you run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined data members of the structure as pointers to **non-const** character strings.

```
struct shirt {
char *size;
char *colour;
} ;
```

However in the function you are assigning pointers to `const` character strings to pointers to `non-const` character strings

```
crea[i].size = wsize[i%5];
crea[i].colour = wcolour[i%4];
```

See declarations of  wsize and wcolour in the parameter list

```
const char *wsize[] , const char *wcolour[]
```

You may not do that.

Define the data members as pointers to const strings

```
struct shirt {
const char *size;
const char *colour;
} ;
```

Or define the parameters as having type of pointers to non-const strings

```
char *wsize[] , char *wcolour[]
```

In this case you have to change also the definitions of the corresponding arguments

```
char *sizearray[] = {"xs","s","m","l","xl"};
char *colourarray[] = {"black","blue","yellow","orange"};
```

In C strings literals have types of non-const arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Here your function takes a const pointer to a Camicia

```
void loadshirt (Camicia const * crea, const char *wsize[] , const char *wcolour[]) {
```

And 3 lines later you try to modify crea :

```
crea[i].size = wsize[i%5];
crea[i].colour = wcolour[i%4];
```

You can't do that.
When the compiler says something along the lines of `X discards 'const' qualifier` it means exactly that. Something is const, but you're trying to modify it as if it weren't.

It's important to try to understand the compiler's error messages, you'll save a lot of time.

Now if you want to fix the function, first you'll need to remove the const qualifier from `crea` in the list of parameters.

But also note that here wsize and wcolour are const, while Camicia is defined like this:

```
struct shirt {
char *size;
char *colour;
} ;
typedef struct shirt Camicia;
```

Either make your struct `Camicia` store const char* or modify the other parameters to be char*. Since you're using string literals in main, you'll probably want everything to be const char*.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a `non-const` pointer to a `const` pointer, you can't modify the contents the `const` pointer points to, but if you discard `const` qualifier you can do it through the new `non-const` pointer, so the compiler is warning you about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
to avoid the runtime seg fault events,
the following code will work correctly.
this code takes into account that the arrays in main()
are actually an array of pointers to char* (I.E. strings)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SHIRTS (50)

struct shirt {
    const char *size;
    const char *colour;
} ;

// struct shirt * const says the pointer is const, 
// not that the contents of where the pointer points is const
void loadshirt (struct shirt * const, const char **, const char **);


int main (void) {

    struct shirt collezione[MAX_SHIRTS];

    // create two arrays of const pointers to consts
    const char const *pSize[]   = {"xs","s","m","l","xl"}; 
    const char const *pColour[] = {"black","blue","yellow","orange"}; 

    loadshirt(collezione, pSize, pColour);

    printf("%s\n",collezione[4].size);
    printf("%s\n",collezione[4].colour);

    return 0;
}


void loadshirt (struct shirt * const crea, const char **pSize , const char **pColour)
{

    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<MAX_SHIRTS; i++)
    {
        crea[i].size   = pSize[i%5];
        crea[i].colour = pColour[i%4];
    }
}
```